# Separate words with commas in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to use a formula in Excel to separate a bunch of words in a cell with a comma. If there are more than 5 words in the cell, I just want to get the first 5 words. To get the first five words in a cell and separate them by a comma I use this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^",5))-1), " ", ", ")
```

This works fine. But the problem with this, because of the number 5 here, if I a cell contains less than 5 words, I get an error. I tried to substitute the 5 with this:

```
LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1
```

So my function becomes this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","^",LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1))-1), " ", ", ")
```

But this doesn't work, it gives me an error. Any idea how I can do this please?

Also I would like to ignore the first word if its first character is "-" (without the quotes) and just start from the second word. So in other words, I want something like this:

I love my life very much **should return** I, love, my, life, very
- I love my life very much **should return** I, love, my, life, very (the "-" is ignored")
I love my **should return** I, love, my

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Will your data always have a space with the "-", "- ", and never have a space before a "-", " - ", and will there ever be a dash anywhere in the data you want to keep?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a somewhat different approach. Aside from the "less than 5" issue, it also deals with the "5 words with no space at the end" issue:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(A1 & "^"," ","^",5))-1)
```

EDIT 1: I just noticed the part about the leading "- ". My addition isn't very elegant, but it deals with it, and also `TRIMS` any trailing spaces:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(IF(LEFT(A1,2)="- ",MID(A1,3,999),A1),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEFT(A1,2)="- ",MID(A1,3,999),A1) & "^"," ","^",5))-1))
```

EDIT 2: Oh yeah, commas:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(IF(LEFT(A1,2)="- ",MID(A1,3,999),A1),FIND("^",SUBSTITUTE(IF(LEFT(A1,2)="- ",MID(A1,3,999),A1) & "^"," ","^",5))-1))," ",",")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-"," "))," ",","),",",REPT(" ",99),5),99))

Comment: That one maybe "fails" on something like "I love my brother-in-law's wife".

Comment: I tried to check if other posters handled this problem, so entered " - I love my brother-in-law's wife" in your formula to get " -,I,love,my". I have "continental" syntax, perhaps something went wrong during converting.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is, but mine works for me with that phrase, and your doesn't. The question seems somewhat prone to confusion, and if I had to solve it for myself, I'd start with Search and Replace to remove the leading dashes.

Comment: It does fail on hyphenated words, but so does mine if there isn't a leading dash. Slightly modify it like this. `=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(A1),2),"-"," ")&MID(TRIM(A1),3,999))," ",","),",",REPT(" ",99),5),99))` The only thing that wont work for is a hyphenated word with one letter before the hyphen (r-op) at the beginning. @Doug Glancy, I believe Istvan is pointing out that your formula acts up when there are extra spaces before or after the "- " or No space after dash. If you have time can you check mine out. The poster says is wrong, but I can't see it

Comment: Sorry for second comment. A small adjustment to previous comment makes this formula flawless: `=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),"-"," ")&MID(TRIM(A1),2,999))," ",","),",",REPT(" ",99),5),99))`

Comment: It would be nice to hear from the OP as we all slave away at our superformulas. Meanwhile "flawless" is good enough for my +1. I'll re-make my earlier point that I wouldn't try to clean up data this way myself. A couple of search and replaces are more reliable, I think.

Comment: I call my excel syntax ’continental’ (do not know the correct word) as the character separating the arguments is not a comma, but a semicolon, so each formula presented here should be converted with great care to evaluate. Just to mention: the asker’s first formula, which does not handle ’brother-in-law’ either as you request is said ’To work fine” – he must know better.
Besides, that question can not be solved in a mechanical way, for example, I would not treat ’Liverpool-Galataseray’ or ’Obama-Putin talks’ as one word.

Answer (score 1):

This will work even if there is **not a space** after the dash or if there are **extra spaces** in the text. Often I find that input is not very *clean*.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",1)),
" ","*",5),IFERROR(FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","",1)),
" ","*",5))-1,999))," ",",")
```

[image: Example of possible spaces or missing spaces]

**Edit:** After commenting on István's, I made mine flawless too.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),"-","  ",1)
&MID(TRIM(A1),2,999))," ","*",5),IFERROR(FIND("*",SUBSTITUTE(
TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(TRIM(A1),1),"-","",1)&MID(TRIM(A1),2,999))," ","*",5))-1,999))," ",",")
```

[image: Fixes all now]

But I think his is more elegant.

Comment: This leaves a comma at the beginning of the result when I have a "-" at the beginning of the string, how do I get rid of that comma?

Comment: @user765368 No it doesn't. Please provide an example where this is happening.

Comment: Oh wait, you made István's flawless, and now yours. +1 to you too!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ","",1))&" "," ",", "),", ","|",MIN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ","",1))&" "," ",", "))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ","",1))&" "," ",", ")," ","")),5)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ","",1))&" "," ",", "),", ","|",MIN(LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ","",1))&" "," ",", "))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"- ","",1))&" "," ",", ")," ","")),5)))-1),",,",",")
```

The formula works by taking the following steps:

- Remove any leading dash-space
- Trim any leading or trailing spaces
- Insert comma-spaces in place of spaces and add a trailing comma-space
- Calculate the lesser of 5 and the number of words in the string
- Put in "|" in place of either the fifth comma-space or the trailing comma-space if the string is less than five words
- Determine the position of the "|"
- Strip off the "|" and all characters to the right of it
- Remove any doubled commas due to any single embedded commas in the initial string

If you are willing to consider a VBA solution, this complex expression can be replaced by a user-defined function:

```
Function words5(InputString As String) As String
    Dim wordArray As Variant
    wordArray = Split(Trim(Replace(InputString, _        'remove "-", put words into array
        "-", "", , 1)), " ")
    ReDim Preserve wordArray(LBound(wordArray) To _      'drop all but the first 5 words
        WorksheetFunction.Min(UBound(wordArray), 5 - 1))
    words5 = Replace(Join(wordArray, ", "), ",,", ",")   'rejoin the words with ", "
End Function                                             'separator
```

On the plus side of using this code is its maintainability compared to the worksheet formula, which  impossible to understand or safely alter without access to the original building blocks that were combined into the single expression.

The code would have to be installed in the workbook in which it is used or in either the standard Personal.xlsb workbook or an addin workbook.

To use the function, copy and paste it into a standard module, which can be inserted into a workbook via the VBA editor. You can open the editor with the `Visual Basic` button on the `Developer tab of the ribbon.

Comment: This leaves a comma at the beginning of the result when I have a "-" at the beginning of the string, how do I get rid of that comma?

Comment: Is the "-" always followed by a space?

Comment: Yes it is always followed by at least one space

Comment: See my amended answer, user765368.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd throw my hat in the ring also.  I think this formula should cover the bases:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1&" ","- ",""))," ",REPT(" ",99)),99*5))," ",",")
```